# How do I change the default gemfile created with 'rails new' command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have recently experienced an issue where I must add the following to my gemfile:

```
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

I must do this to avoid a javascript runtime error that occurs when starting the rails server.  I would like to have this modification added to all new gemfiles created with the rails new command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [application templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#application-templates).

Answer (score 4):

Rails documentation on [Application Templates](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html)

If you want the option to customize each app individually instead of having a rigid template, a really good option is [Rails Composer](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/). It prompts you about common gems during setup, and it nails a lot of the more common gems.

Finally, if you like Rails Composer, but want to be able to re-use application templates, check out [Rails Apps Composer](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_apps_composer). I haven't looked into this too much, but it seems to give you a lot of flexibility while doing most of the heavy lifting for you.