# Import a gemset from RVM into a Rails project.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

If I create a gemlist in RVM and then make a new rails project, can I fills the Rails project's Gemfile with the gems in that gemlist?

Comment: I think that the only way is to build some utility for such thing.

Answer (score 3):

You should export your Gemset using,

`rvm gemset export Gemfile`

where gemset is the name of the Gemset you had created.

[RVM Gemsets](http://rvm.io/gemsets)
https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/982

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the stackoverflow question [How do I change the default gemfile created with 'rails new' command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548267/how-do-i-change-the-default-gemfile-created-with-rails-new-command) which, while not answering my question, divulges an approach which manages to implement the functionality I was searching for with my question - namely, for one to be able to use a user-specified list of gems to be incorporated into a new Rails project's Gemfile. Also, the answer was to look to "Application Templates" - see here in the Rails Guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#application-templates

Stevanity's answer is relevant as well, because, although I didn't specifically mention in my original question that I was looking for a way to share lists of gems between gemlists, I was curious about that. Thanks!